# WARN: Could not find a node that matches the configured _HSLayer2Nodes set

Tags: configuration, tor-install, debian

can anyone explain to me, how to interpret this Log-Message?

```
[WARN] Could not find a node that matches the configured _HSLayer2Nodes set
```

Running Tor `0.4.7.7` on `Debian Bullseye`.

Comment: This might be a bug. You can make a bug report at https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/core/tor/-/issues